# Yii Model: convert table name to lower case

Tags: php, mysql, yii, model, naming-conventions

Existing application using Yii works just fine with a database which has all of its tables starting with an uppercase letter (yes, I know, not a good scenario but it is what it is), for example, `Users`. So the table name specified in the active model is also `Users`.

However, I had to deploy the application on another server and there the database script automatically created the tables in the database with lowercase. Now the table name in the code in the Yii model is `Users` while the actual name in the database is `users` which ends up blowing up in runtime as Yii cannot find the tables in the database.

I could go through all of the models and manually change the uppercase to lowercase, however, there should be a smarter way to do it I reckon?

Answer (score 0):

first update below line in your my.cnf or my.ini file on new server, which should be 1 in your new server, so either just comment this entry or set as 0-

```
lower_case_table_names = 0
```

Then again restore your backup on this server.

Note: Existing databsae will not work, so need to restore whole db again from old server backup.

Comment: The server is remote, is there a way to do that through phpmyadmin?

Comment: i think you should have old server backup from which you prepared new server, so after such changes in conf file restore that backup if you feel that this backup is valid for you otherwise take a fresh backup from old server and restore on this server...yes you can do it by any way from your phpmyadmin also..

Comment: but conf file changes will be possible only from server and mysql service restart will be required before restoration.

Comment: I have no problem restoring the database but I am not able to do the conf file change on the server to start with :(

Comment: approach to your db admin/system admin or whoever managing server/database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by update the yii framework CActiveRecord file in

```
path : yii/framework/ar/CActiveRecord.php
```

change tableName function to

```
public function tableName()
{
    return strtolower(get_class($this));
}
```

but this change will affect all other yii projects.

Comment: Yeah, not really a fan of changing framework core files :(